# Is it possible to share Local Temp table between SQLCLR triggers across a Linked Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, temp-tables, linked-server, sqlclr

I need to implement a Distributed transaction for a third party product. I have two SQL Servers and two SQLCLR triggers. I want to access the local temp table value from the second trigger context, which is on another instance. Is it possible?

```
//Server 1
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlTrigger (Name="SqlTrigger1", Target="Table1", Event="FOR INSERT")]
 public static void SqlTrigger1 ()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            // Create #Temp table
            // Insert some data             
            // Fire trigger Server 2 via Dblink
         }
    }


//Server 2
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlTrigger (Name="SqlTrigger1", Target="Table1", Event="FOR INSERT")]
 public static void SqlTrigger2 ()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            Read #Temp table  ???
         }
    }
```

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/179361). You may benefit from taking a step back and explaining what you are trying to do, and why you think two CLR triggers both accessing a temporary table is the best solution, and someone will tell you why it is not (I don't know what the issue is, but I can say with 99.9% certainty that using CLR triggers to a linked server is not the optimal solution)

Comment: The problem is : I need to implement Distrubuted transaction for a third party product so no source code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate answer has nothing to do with SQLCLR. It is not even conceptually possible to access a local temporary table (or stored procedure) across instances because like any other object, they are local to the instance that they are created on. And when using a Linked Server, there is no way to access the calling session, so a reference back to the local temporary table on Server 1 will never be accessible by code running on Server 2.

Also, while it is at least possible to access a global temporary table between instances (because those are visible to all sessions), that would still require an additional Linked Server to be created on Server 2 that points back to Server 1 because that is where the global temporary table would exist. That's a bit messy, and offers no advantages over creating a real table (unless you create the global temporary table to include a newly created GUID value as part of its name, but then you still need to transfer *that* value over to Server 2 in order to build the correct reference back to Server 1, which will need to happen in Dynamic SQL).

Clarification from the O.P.:

> When user call query `insert into dbo.Account (Name) values('something')` I intercept this with clr trigger and execute the same query on server2 `insert into Server2.dbo.Account (Name) values('something')` and i need to shared context in this transaction for example a guid variable.

There is no such thing as a "shard context" between instances. Whatever data and/or values are needed in both places need to be passed into the remote instance. In this case, you can package up the data as XML in an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` variable, and execute a stored procedure on Server 2, passing in that `NVARCHAR(MAX)` value, convert it to `XML` in the stored procedure, and unpack it using `.nodes()`. Then you can additionally pass in individual scalar values as other parameters to the remote stored procedure. For example:

```
DECLARE @DataToTransfer NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SomeGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

SET @DataToTransfer = (
    SELECT *
    FROM   inserted
    FOR XML RAW('row')
  );

EXEC [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[StoredProcedureName]
    @Param1 = @DataToTransfer,
    @Param2 = @SomeGuid;
```

The approach shown above works quite well. I have used it to transfer millions of rows per day from 18 production servers to a single archive server. Calling a remote stored procedure has less locking issues than attempting to do the straight DML / `INSERT` statement over the Linked Server. Also, this approach allows for sending both the table of data (packaged as XML) and individual variable values (e.g. the Guid you mentioned).

The remote stored procedure -- referenced in the `EXEC` in the example code above -- will be executed locally on Server 2, so it can create a local temporary table that the Trigger on the remote table will have access to, or use either [SET CONTEXT_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) or, if using SQL Server 2016 (or newer), use [sp_set_session_context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt605113.aspx).

Also, as you may have noticed, none of this has anything to do with SQLCLR. I see no reason to introduce the additional complexity of having this in SQLCLR when you will be using none of the benefits of SQLCLR triggers / objects.

Comment: When user call  query `insert into dbo.Account (Name) values('something') ` I intercept this with clr trigger and  execute the same query on server2   `insert into Server2.dbo.Account (Name) values('something')` and i need to shared context in this transaction  for example a guid variable

Answer (score 0):

With a local temp table no, but with a global temp table (two pound signs: `##globalTemp` instead of `#temp`) you should be able to.  That being said, it's likely not a good idea because you never know if `##globalTemp` table would exist or not.  Who should be creating it?

> There are two types of temporary tables: local and global. Local
>   temporary tables are visible only to their creators during the same
>   connection to an instance of SQL Server as when the tables were first
>   created or referenced. Local temporary tables are deleted after the
>   user disconnects from the instance of SQL Server. Global temporary
>   tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are
>   created, and are deleted when all users that are referencing the table
>   disconnect from the instance of SQL Server.

Comment: A global ##temp table is almost never the answer to any problem. The primary reason is that it inhibits concurrency to the point that a permanent, session-keyed table makes a whole lot more sense.